# jQuery - How to get values out of a selection object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get out certain values from a selection object in jQuery.

Right now I have the values I need posted out in the console.log - but only the whole object. The problem is there is multiple objects and I need to get out the id - shown here:

From the console:

```
[s, s]
    0: s
    _changing: false
    _events: Object
    _listenId: "l89"
    _pending: false
    _previousAttributes: Object
    attributes: Object
    changed: Object
    cid: "c46"
    collection: s
    id: 72
    __proto__: n

    1: s
    _changing: false
    _events: Object
    _listenId: "l91"
    _pending: false
    _previousAttributes: Object
    attributes: Object
    changed: Object
    cid: "c47"
    collection: s
    id: 71
    __proto__: n
    length: 2
    __proto__: Array[0]
```

What I need here is to push the id's 72 and 71 into an array that I can use to set an input value.

Right now I have this:

```
.on('select', function(e){

           var uploaded_image = image.state().get('selection').each(function(){ 
                //console.log('running');
            });


            console.log(uploaded_image);

            var image_id = uploaded_image['id'];

            $('#image_id').val(image_id);
            $('#image_url').val(image_url);
        });
```

Comment: inside your each ...`$(this).id`?

Comment: [_.pluck(uploaded_image, 'id')](http://underscorejs.org/#pluck)

Comment: @Neil - Works!:) Thanks!

Comment: It's `deferred.state()` but I don't see a deferred object